# Time series data

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series, data-processing, multivariate-time-series

I have an Excel file and there are two columns in it, I want to combine them, but one of them is in datetime form and the other is object (actually time). What I want to do is convert the object one to datetime format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ9nW.jpg)

I've tried everything I can think of but I keep getting an error.
Edit :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrqZJ.png)

import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/data.xlsx')
dataFrame.head()
output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXFKE.png)
and my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfgBp.png)

Comment: so what is the error

Comment: Please show your code in its current form, and show what error you are getting. Perhaps even suggest how you would like the final output to look like. Better questions result in better answers.

Comment: I have attached the error image.

Comment: Please provide example data and code as text instead of image. That way, it is much simpler for others to reproduce the problem and provide good advice.

Comment: I have attached the images

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding? You'd want to split "Time" column on space and take 0 index. Finally use .cat to concatenate the string columns together. Next .pop old columns and finally wrap it all in to_datetime.

```
df["Time"] = df["Time"].str.split(r"\s+").str[0]
df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop("Date").astype(str).str.cat(df.pop("Time"), sep=" "))
```

Comment: I just want to change the "time" column to "datetime" and add it to the "date" column

Comment: thats essentially what my answer does

Comment: yes ıts work but It only outputs as "date", shouldn't it have "time" in it?

Comment: yeah it concats both date and time into datetime

Comment: hello thank you give me answer its work but ı do first line ".str[1]"  and its is correctly work thanks again